# EOL error while scanning

Tags: python, string, printing, eol

I've been having trouble with this python 3.3.0 code. It gives me an EOL error. This is the code:

```
print('You own a'," ".join(profile['inventory'])
```

I haven't tried anything else because I don't really know what an EOL error is.

Comment: Missing closing parenthesis? EOL stands for End Of Line.

Answer (score 1):

When running your code, you should get something like `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`. This is because you forgot to close your parenthesis with your print function.

```
print('You own a'," ".join(profile['inventory'])) # Add an extra )
```